# AngularJS - Setting value of radio button built using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

Here's the HTML :

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="answer in answers">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedAnswer" name="answerText" value="{{answer.answerID}}"/>
            <label>{{answer.answerText}}            
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The need is to store the selected answer into `LocalStorage` and whenever the question shows up again, mark the radio button corresponding to that answer.
I'm able to store it in `LocalStorage`, retrieve it, but when I update the model, it doesn't select the radio button on the UI.

In my controller, I'm simply calling -

```
$scope.selectedAnswer = value.answerID;
```

where value points to the answer stored in the `LocalStorage`.
Please help.

---

EDIT:

A little more detail :

I'm managing the entire quiz page using a single route and controller. When one question is done, I fetch the next question and its corresponding answers. While populating the `answers` array in the controller (`$scope.answers`), I'm checking to match their IDs with the answer stored in the `LocalStorage`. Between each question, the `answers` array is emptied and populated again.

Comment: It looks like you're using a child and a parent controller. Can you show just enough of the enough to cover both the child and the parent controller? Also, which controller are you setting $scope.selectedAnswer = value.answerID?

Comment: Nopes. There are no child/parent controllers, just one controller assigned to the partial. The reason you see `$parent$` in `ng-model` is because `ng-repeat` creates it's own `$scope`.

Comment: When you say "LocalStorage" do you mean in the JavaScript ? or in this case the $scope?

Comment: @njfife by `LocalStorage` I mean the HTML5 `LocalStorage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should be using `ng-value` to do this since it is an angular expression and not a text value. Using just value as you did worked in Plnkr but I know that sometimes it does not.

Also in general I have found that using the `ng-controller="<ControllerName> as <ThisRef>"` works a lot better in most cases. There are times when you still need the $scope variable (Like for form validation) but normally I have fewer scoping issues when using the controllers "this" variable over the $scope.

I made an example using the method I described:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XV3we6SDmmLmUGSwdVVT?p=preview

If your question has to do with HTML 5 Local Storage let me know, I wasn't sure

---

**EDIT:**
Alternatively you can try using `$scope.$apply();` to accomplish this. If the scope is not in sync with the view then apply should fix that.

Here is another plnkr showing how I would generally do something like that. Note that the $apply is 100% not needed in that example but likely is needed in yours.

Here is my example:

```
    $scope.updateModel = function(value) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.selectedAnswer = value;
        });
      });
    };
```

Notice I am using $timeout to make sure it doesn't happen while there is a digest in progress.

http://plnkr.co/edit/O7CBfTiWPrsbthFKlAOZ?p=preview

I hope this edit helps =)

Comment: You're right. I was about to suggest the ControllerAs syntax next, but you beat me to it.

Comment: I tried `ng-value` too, doesn't work. And yes, my question is regarding `HTML5 LocalStorage` but I don't think that should be a problem, as I'm just storing the answer IDs and retrieving them.

Comment: So is my plunkr not accomplishing what you are trying to do? Maybe I am not understanding the question

Comment: Your plunkr works fine, but doesn't work for my scenario. I should probably edit the question to add more details.

Comment: Yeah I would need more code, if you look in the debugger and check the value of 'value' when the function that sets '$scope.selectedAnswer' does it contain the data you are expecting? If not then the issue is not angular related

Comment: It is containing the data I'm expecting. Even `$scope.selectedAnswer` contains the correct value. I'm not sure why isn't it updating on the UI. I've updated the question to explain the flow of my app, not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: Are you using the "Controller as" notation in your app?

Comment: I'm using partials, so there's no explicit declaration of ng-controller. Let me include that and try.

Comment: There's got to be a better way. I'm ending up changing a lot of my controller code if I have to use "Controller as" notation. And the watchers too.

Comment: You could manually trigger apply on the scope after you update the value. That will probably fix it as well, but it is not as clean: '$scope.$apply()'

Comment: `$scope.$apply()` looked promising. But didn't work. I'm really annoyed now. Been stuck with this for too long. I get the error `$apply() already in progress`.

Comment: Generally using $timeout will push the apply to the end of the digest. Did you do it with $timeout?

Comment: `$timeout` did it. Could you add another edit mentioning `$timeout`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Since you only have one controller, you don't need to specify $parent.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="answer in answers">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedAnswer" name="answerText" value="{{answer.answerID}}"/>
            <label>{{answer.answerText}}            
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you do, sorry, but this is not right, ng-repeat has it's own scope your method will not yield the expected result

Comment: He is a plnkr showing that is not right: http://plnkr.co/edit/BCaualli3sMJeM1YVdjF?p=preview
You really do WANT it to work that way, it makes ng-repeat much more useful